# Performance issue rendering large tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, datatables

I'm trying to use html tables to show large quantities of data. In my case a matrix of 260 columns and 117 rows.

jQuery/Ajax is used to get the data. And DataTables + Scroller to show it all. The browser freezes for a number of seconds to render it all. Which I think is only normal - regarding the single-threaded nature of javascript.

Unfortunately, once it is rendered, the browser is still in trouble. The response becomes very sluggish. Resizing the window, popping up dev tools, etc... Presumable because it runs the rendering process again ? Or maybe the memory consumption goes through the roof ? I have no clue.

Scroller is used because there are *many* more rows to come. Which works beautifully with a modest number of columns. It only fetches and shows the visible rows. In practice there is no limit to the rows. Alas, this is not the case for the columns. They are always all included.

Does somebody know how to apply the same trick "horizontally" ? By only including the visible columns into the DOM ?

**UPDATE**

I've prepared an example on JSFiddle: [url to code](http://jsfiddle.net/jan_goyvaerts/DuA8v/25/)

```
Why does SO need code ?
```

First press "Add Big table" and then "Fill table". Wait for a few seconds to see the table appear. The spent time is displayed too. The "render" time is basically the duration of the DT call. The "build" time is the time spent to create the whole thing - apart from calling DT.

The styling of the result is not really what we have here - but the intended result is there: Showing it takes 4/5s to render it. I'm no JS/CSS/... guru; hence my call for help to find out what's going on.

To "simulate" the server, the DT settings object is converted into a string and then back into a JSON object. And only then fed to DT.

Is there something obvious I can try to make this process go faster ?

Comment: What kind of browser / OS are you using? Do you happen to have a online example of the page you're having trouble with?

Comment: Version 33.0.1750.152 Debian 7.4 (256984). The dev tools show a massive amount of time spent in rendering. But Firefox seems to have the same problem.

Comment: How does you initialize the datatable?

Comment: BTW, if we got a dime for every performance question regarding jQuery dataTables we would all be billionaires :) dataTables is **really** great, but it is due to its internal jQuery setup not so great for tables with many rows (a few thousand top) and / or an overwhelming amount of columns.

Comment: For the rows Scroller is a good solution. We use it with hundreds of thousands of rows. No big deal. It's the columns ! :-)

Comment: We use the ajax serverside configuration - there is a rest web service collecting the array of data and sending the whole thing back.

Answer (score 2):

The data-tables plugin is so responsive because it tries loading all data first and then you can sort/search as needed.What we can and should do in case of large datasets is to load as much data as can be handled in one view and then on click of a link or button load the next view. For a large number of rows it is fairly obvious to implement pages. *[For those that use LINQ, this can be done by using Skip (pagesize(n)) and Take (pagesize).]*

This is called **pagination** and can be enabled automatically via the jQuery data-tables API. This along with **server-side processing** will vastly increase the performance of any jQuery data-table.

For a large number of columns, also load only say 10 columns that fit in your view and then show  a link to load more. When the link is clicked, load the next 10 columns. Keep a count of how many times it has been clicked, this will help you to understand how many columns to skip.

For more information on server side processing see http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Any experience with DataTables for this ? :-)

Comment: See if you do not allow drag and drop of columns i.e. the columns are in some order it is fairly easy to show some columns first,then on some event like click of Show more button hit the server with some parameter as to what columns to pull and show the same. For more info on how to use server-side processing,see http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: I added an edit to further explain the jQuery data-tables application of this

Answer (score 0):

For large data-sets, I've found myself forced to use `divs` instead of table markup.

Several reasons why browsers can handle these better, mainly the entire table needs to be calculated before rendering.

Comment: Eh, no. Don't use divs for tabular data. Just like you shouldn't use tables for site structure.

Comment: Anyway, I'd rather use the tags for what they're meant. I presume the rendering engine does things differently when it knows it's a tabular data and not a collection of rectangles.

Comment: While I agree generally it's better to stick to convention, for large tables of data there really is a noticeable difference in rendering time, and I feel it's a good solution without bringing in extra js libraries. (Im talking in the order of 100's of rows)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've a lot of columns, `table-layout: fixed` would probably be helpful.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Comment: @SirajHussain: yes, I did. Why the downvote? Using fixed table layouts dramatically improves rendering speed of large tables.

Answer (score -1):

first hide the page after putting data in table and than show it using setTimeout function. I don't know that it will work or not in your app but it's working in my app..

ex

```
$("yourId").hide();
setTimeout(function(){
$("yourId").show();
},10),
```

May be it will work for you.

Comment: That's "fixing" symptoms, not the actual problem.
*"Oh, it takes 1 minute to render?"* *"Yup, it's not as efficient as it could be"* *"That's okay, we'll just add a delay before showing the table"*

Comment: Well, for the initial render it helps to add the rows piecemeal from a number of timeout tasks. The rows appear shortly after the table was shown. Which is actually cool. But it still poses the problem of what happens after the table is shown.

Comment: jan can you explane more what you want say.

Comment: Well, regardless the technique used to put the markup into the DOM tree, Chrome becomes very sluggish after that. What makes me think 30K cells is a bit too much on the browser's stomach.